# XPath: Wrapping div tag around paragraphs between H3 tags

Tags: xpath

I want to wrap a div around a paragraph using only PHP and XPath - all I know is that the text is somewhere between two headlines

EXAMPLE

```
<h3>Headline 1</h3>

<p>TEXT</p>

<h3>Headline 2</h3>

<p>TEXT</p>
```

How would this work and is Xpath a sensible solution? I would like to wrap a div around the first, preferably ALL paragraphs that follow

Comment: Xpath doesn't wrap. Xpath points to.

Comment: You need to use either XQuery or XSLT for doing this with "XML native" query languages.